# Use external variable in Jade

Tags: javascript, variables, pug

I have a variable, `test`, in `script.js`. I reference `script.js` in the head of my `index.jade` document like this: `script(type="text/javascript")(src="scripts/script.js")`.

In my `index.jade` file, I need to use that `test` variable, but when I try to, in almost all cases I get an error saying `'test' is not defined`.

I've found that something like `body(onload="alert(test);")` can access the `test` variable, but something like `p #{test}` or `p= test` cannot access  it, which is really what I need to work.

So how can I pass a variable from `script.js` into `index.jade` so that Jade will recognize it? Thanks in advance for any advice you might have.

Comment: have you tried passing your `colors` array into jade as a local variable? And what do you mean with `externally`: on the server or inside another javascript file or somewhere else?

Comment: @zeMirco - Sorry to be unclear; by externally, I mean another Javascript file that's linked to my Jade file. The array works fine when it's declared inside the block of jade, as I wrote in my question. The problem is that I want to declare it globally in my Javascript file and be able to access it in my Jade file.

Answer (score 4):

This is server side javascript:

```
- var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

And this is client side:

```
body(onload="alert(colors);")
```

Because of this colors on client side is undefined. You can do this:

```
body(onload="alert(#{colors});")
```

EDIT:

If colors is client side javascript variable, then you should do it like this:

```
ul#myul

script
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var ul = document.getElementById('myul');
        for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = colors[i];
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    })
```

EDIT:

test is client side variable and cannot be used as server side js variable. to use it with jade, you should first pass it from server like this in nodejs:

```
res.render('myviewpath', { test: test });
```

Comment: Actually, when `colors` is stored externally, onload="alert(colors)" works whereas alert(#{colors}) does not. Let's say I wanted to put each color in the array `colors` into a `li` in Jade. Is there a way to do that if the array I'm accessing is not stored in the Jade file? That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks. Please take a look at my edited question since I think I was being unclear.

Comment: @ben test is client side variable and cannot be used as server side js variable. to use it with jade, you should first pass it from server like this in nodejs: res.render('myviewpath', { test: test });

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. If you edit your answer accordingly I'll be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: @ben no need to accept it if you have any more problems, let's fight them :)